# How would I open a .csv file with VBA and read all the data?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

When I extract my data from this one software into raw text it separates the values with commas and quotation marks for the majority of the file. Except in certain cases the data has a line break. When I save it as a .csv and open it, the data is cleanly formatted into a proper table.
However, if I attempt the same process with `QueryTables`it processes the enter character as a new line.

I have two different approaches in two different subprograms
The first is able to read the number of rows and columns properly, but since it uses the `QueryTables` method it reads that enter charachter as a new line.
The code for this approach is below:

```
Private Sub OpenCSVFile()
With ThisWorkbook
        Set primeSheet = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        primeSheet.Name = "Temp"
End With
Set informationRange = primeSheet.Range("A1")
xAddress = informationRange.Address
With primeSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & strPath, primeSheet.Range(xAddress))
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells 
    .SaveData = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

rowLength = primeSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
colLength = primeSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

The other method keeps the formatting intact as to when I regularly open .csv files of my extracted data, but it is unable to read the number of rows and lengths, and returns a value for 1 for each.

```
 Private Sub OpenCSV()
 Set primeBook = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
 With primeBook
     rowLength = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     colLength = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set informationRange = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(colLength, rowLength))
End Sub
```

How would you recommend I address my issue and read the contents of the csv file while ensuring no weird line breaks.

Comment: I use methods similar to either of your approaches at certain points, but I haven't had the issue of returning a rowlength/column length of one before.

I'm inherently mistrustful of using `.End(xlDown)`, etc to find the useful range as it stops at the first gap in the data - for example I have csv data where the top left cell is some meta data type stuff, and the actual real data starts five rows down - this would return the same issue as you in this case. 

Consider changing to an approach that uses the `.Find` method (searching up from the bottom right) and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Private Sub OpenCSV()
 Set primeBook = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
 With primeBook.Sheet1
     rowLength = .usedrange.rows.count
     colLength = .usedrange.columns.count
End With
Set informationRange = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(colLength, rowLength))
End Sub
```